# Segmentation fault em implementação de cliente/servidor

Tags: c++, socket, cliente-servidor

Olá, estou implementando o jogo 21(BlackJack) em C++ em um ambiente Linux,
ao decorrer da execução ele apresenta o erro Segmentation fault, o problema é que não estou conseguindo identificar o gerador do erro. O mesmo aparece após o primeiro loop do while acontecer. 
Estou executando o código com o 'netcat',ele está substituindo o meu cliente. Ele chega a enviar pela primeira vez os dados para o servidor e recebe o que o servidor enviou e logo após apresenta o Segmentation fault.
A propósito estou usando socket.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>             
#include <sys/socket.h>   // socket
#include <arpa/inet.h>    // inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>       // write

using namespace std;


int client_sock;
struct sockaddr_in server, client;
int socket_desc, c, read_size;
char client_message[1000];
int PORTA = 4000;
int totalj = 0;

void imprime(int sock, string m);
void processarCliente();
int criar_socket_server();
int randomInteger(int low, int high);
void limpa_Buffer();
void faz_Chamada(char variavel);
void processarPC();

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {
    int ok = 1;
    //imprime(0, "this is a test!!!");
    criar_socket_server();

    do {
        processarCliente();

    } while (ok);

    return 0;
}

void imprime(int sock, string m) {
    write(sock, m.c_str(), m.size()); //write n aceita string, logo tranformei em vetor de char
}

int criar_socket_server() {

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        cout << "Could not create socket\n";
    }
    cout << "Socket created\n";

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // qualquer endereco
    server.sin_port = htons(PORTA); // porta a esperar por conexoes
    //Bind
    while (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (server)) < 0) {//socket esc -> sockfd//server->local
        //print the error message
        PORTA++;
        cout << "Mundando para a porta " << PORTA << "\n";
        server.sin_port = htons(PORTA); // porta a esperar por conexoes
    }
    cout << "bind done\n";

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
}

void processarCliente() {
    int jogada = 0;
    totalj = 0;
    char temp;
    //Accept and incoming connection
    c = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &client, (socklen_t*) & c);

    imprime(client_sock, "Bem Vindo ao BlackJack em C!!\n Você tem que fazer 21 pontos para ganhar, porém sem estourar esse limite, podendo parar após cada jogada.");


    //Receive a message from client
    while ((read_size = recv(client_sock, client_message, 1000, 0)) > 0) {


        if (client_message[0] == 's' || client_message[0] == 'S')//buffer -> client_mes
        {

            jogada = randomInteger(1, 10);
            totalj = (totalj + jogada);

            if (jogada == 10) {
                temp = '0';
            } else {
                temp = (char) jogada;
            }

            stringstream cc;
            cc << "\n O valor da sua carta eh  " << jogada << " e o seu total de pontos eh " << totalj;
            imprime(client_sock, cc.str()); //str transforma o fluxo de string em string

            if (totalj == 21) {
                imprime(client_sock, "Parabens! Você é o Vencedor! \n");
                close(client_sock);
                totalj = 0;
                break;
            } else if (totalj > 21) {
                stringstream cc;
                cc << "Que pena você perdeu! Os seus pontos estouraram!:\n " << totalj;
                imprime(client_sock, cc.str()); //str transforma o fluxo de string em string
                close(client_sock);
                totalj = 0;
                break;
            }

            faz_Chamada(temp);

            limpa_Buffer();

        } else if (client_message[0] == 'n' || client_message[0] == 'N') {
            stringstream cc;
            cc << "\n Total de pontos: " << totalj;
            imprime(client_sock, cc.str()); //str transforma o fluxo de string em string
            close(client_sock);
            totalj = 0;
            break;
        }

    }
}

int randomInteger(int low, int high) {
    int k;
    double d;
    srand(time(NULL));
    d = (double) rand() / ((double) RAND_MAX + 1);
    k = d * (high - low + 1);

    return low + k;
}

void limpa_Buffer() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
        client_message[i] = ' ';
    }
}

void faz_Chamada(char variavel) {
    cout << "fez chamada no cliente";

    char vet[1];

    vet[0] = variavel;

    limpa_Buffer();

    strcpy(client_message, vet);
    (send(client_sock, client_message, strlen(client_message), 0)); //cliente -> client_sock
    //    buffer[slen] = '\0';
    limpa_Buffer();

}
```

Comment: Quais são os passos para testar seu código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples. Você aloca a variável `client_message` com 1000 bytes:

```
char client_message[1000];
```

Mas então, na chamada de `limpa_Buffer` você faz um laço até 4096:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
    client_message[i] = ' ';
}
```

Logo, a partir do momento em que `i` passa a valer 1000 ou mais, você já está invadindo área de memória não alocada naquela variável. Por isso o erro de segmentação.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Luiz! 
Era Isso mesmo.

Comment: Por nada Aline. Porém, em uma próxima vez que esse tipo de erro acontecer, lembre-se de depurar seu programa. As chances do depurador parar exatamente na linha onde está o problema são muito grandes.